# How to get a callback for css3 transition end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying the following but I get no callback at all

```js
$("#panel").addClass("showPane");
$("#close_wikipedia").on("click", function() {
  $("#panel").addClass("close_wiki");
});

if ($("#panel").hasClass("close_wiki")) {
  $(this).bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function() {
    $("#panel").removeClass("close_wiki showPane");
  });
}
```

```css
#panel {
  position: fixed;
  background: #444;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50vw;
  right: -100vw;
  transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#panel.showPane {
  right: 0;
}
#panel.close_wiki {
  right: -100vw;
  transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel">
  <h2>Wikipedia results</h2>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordionWiki" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true"></div>
  <button id="close_wikipedia" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Close Wiki</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you make a demo?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because you only check if `#panel` has the `close_wiki` class when the pages loads - which will never fire as it's added on button click.

Instead hook the `transitionEnded` event onload and wait for it to fire after the CSS transition completes. Also note that `bind()` is deprecated. You should use `on()` instead. Try this:

```js
$("#close_wikipedia").on("click", function() {
  $("#panel").removeClass("showPane");
});
```

```css
#panel {
  position: fixed;
  background: #444;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50vw;
  right: -100vw;
  transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#panel.showPane {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel" class="showPane">
  <h2>Wikipedia results</h2>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordionWiki" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true"></div>
  <button id="close_wikipedia" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Close Wiki</button>
</div>
```

Also note that you can make the logic much simpler (and remove the need to hook to `transitionEnded` at all by just toggling the `showPane` class on the `#Panel` element.

```js
$('#panel').addClass('showPane');

$("#close_wikipedia").on("click", function() {
  $("#panel").removeClass("showPane");
});
```

```css
#panel {
  position: fixed;
  background: #444;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50vw;
  right: -100vw;
  transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#panel.showPane {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel">
  <h2>Wikipedia results</h2>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordionWiki" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true"></div>
  <button id="close_wikipedia" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Close Wiki</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to not chekc for the close_wiki class on page load and bind event based on it. Since this class is added dynamically on the close_wikipedia click. you can use event delegation to achieve the call back of transition event when close_wiki is clicked.

```js
$("#panel").addClass("showPane");
$("#close_wikipedia").on("click", function() {
  $("#panel").addClass("close_wiki");
});

 $(document).on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd",".close_wiki", function() {
    alert("called");
    $("#panel").removeClass("close_wiki showPane");
  });
```

```css
#panel {
  position: fixed;
  background: #444;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50vw;
  right: -100vw;
  transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#panel.showPane {
  right: 0;
}
#panel.close_wiki {
  right: -100vw;
  transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel">
  <h2>Wikipedia results</h2>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordionWiki" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true"></div>
  <button id="close_wikipedia" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Close Wiki</button>
</div>
```